# Javascript executing PHP does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Right now I am programming a Raspberry Pi robot with wheels for a personal project. I want to control it through an Apache website which is running on the Raspberry. I only want to connect to it locally.
Last night i have done the buttons to control the wheels from the robot. I tried to execute the files which are needed to start the motors through PHP but soon learned that the site always switches, which i dont want it to do, when i just use a `submit` button in a `<form></form>`. So i went on the internet and found something about `ajax`.
Since all buttons are not working, i will just give you an example of one button from my code. They all work the same, they just have different names, directorys and call a different function. All functions are in the same Javascript.
HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../javascript/pfeile/pfeile.js"></script>

    <div class="pfeilvorne" id="submitvorne" style="background-color: transparent;" onClick="vorne()"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function vorne() {
      $.ajax({
        url:"../../php/Pfeile/vorne.php", //the page containing php script
        type: "POST", //request type
        url:"../../php/Pfeile/php.php", //the page containing php script
     });
 }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
exec("sudo killall vorne.bin");
exec("sudo killall hinten.bin");
exec("sudo killall links.bin");
exec("sudo killall rechts.bin");
exec("sudo killall kreis.bin");
exec("sudo /home/pi/Maxwheel/Scripte/Vorne/sketch_apr13a/vorne.bin");
?>
```

I tested the scripts using `sudo ./[Scriptname]` in an `ssh` console and they are working. The buttons also work when i solely use php (But only using php still changes the site....)
I hope you can help me, thank you!

Comment: You can't have two of the same key in a javascript object (url).

Comment: Just to be clear on terminology and methodology, JavaScript does not - cannot - execute PHP; it can merely invoke an HTTP request, e.g. via AJAX, to a file which the server executes via PHP.

Comment: I know that this might not be what you're after, but I recommend using node.js for doing projects such as these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two identical keys (url) in one object. They will be overwritten. Try something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitvorne').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url:"../../php/Pfeile/vorne.php", //the page containing php script
        type: "POST", //request type
     });

     $.ajax({
        url:"../../php/Pfeile/php.php", //the page containing php script
        type: "POST", //request type
     });
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="pfeilvorne" id="submitvorne">
```

Comment: Solved the issue! Thanks :)